Can't change keyboard layout on Ubuntu 22.04.5
My keyboard layout is stuck on a qwerty keyboard even though the laptop has a Belgian azerty keyboard. During login it is azerty, but after that is switches to qwerty. I have tried the following:

Attempted to add a new input source at settings->keyboard->input sources but this doesn't do anything when I select any keyboard and it remains on No input source selected
Tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration and selected a belgian keyboard, I even edited /etc/default/keyboard to XKBLAYOUT="be" and rebooted the laptop, but to no avail.
Found someone saying I should edit the ~/.config/dconf but this directory does not exist. (There are 2 users on my laptop, not sure if that has anything to do with it.)


What do you have set in Settings -> Language and Region -> Formats and in Input Sources under Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources [Edit] your question accordingly and at the same time indicate which version and distro of the OS you are using as that is absent from your post.
